# 0x v3 audit report sha1 hashes

Tags: 0x

Trying to cross reference the sha1 hashes from the audit report here: https://consensys.net/diligence/audits/2019/09/0x-v3-exchange/

And the hashes I generated from the following repo at the 3.0 branch: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-monorepo/commits/3.0

I'm getting different hashes, for each file - take for example the following hashes:

Contract, Consensys Hash, My Generated Hash:

Exchange, cb6733c32d3306348791b83a9ae76460b75555df, 32be96413b0e31510d7e2670f10c984b91d962ef
MixinAssetProxyDispatcher, ee5492092ebea3397d53163cad5cfe8b8050f88e, edd7caf734a0ef407ebfc7262524c9d8592ffa95
MixinExchangeCore, 87f9d192c0d75569ee95705baa9c1cdfd129d7a5, 46f792e6917709e6b3c55d0b3d417f78bd7989f5

Command with output:

```
$ sha1sum Exchange.sol
32be96413b0e31510d7e2670f10c984b91d962ef *Exchange.sol
```

Am i looking at the wrong branch or something?

Comment: The hashes are probably from an older commit, the audit says that some fixes were applied in that branch.

Answer (score 1):

The 3.0 branch would've contained any fixes suggested by the audit process. It seems like the Conensys Diligence doesn't declare the exact commit SHA which they audited but it is contained in the [Trail of Bits audit](https://github.com/trailofbits/publications/blob/master/reviews/0x-protocol.pdf)